# SQL COUNT, how can I add rows with the same name field

Tags: sql

I have a table in sql named `orders` that has these fields: `product_code` , `quantity`.

The `product_code` is not unique. For ex.

```
product_code quantity
product_1 2
product_1 3
product_2 2
product_2 4
```

I would like to count the number of ordered products grouped by `product_code`. 
The results of the above would be:

```
product_1 5
product_2 6
```

any thoughts ?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT product_code, SUM(quantity) FROM orders GROUP BY product_code
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple GROUP? :

```
SELECT 
  product_code,
  SUM(quantity)
FROM
  tbl
GROUP BY product_code
ORDER BY product_code
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Product_code, sum(quantity) as quantity from orders group by product_code
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT product_code, SUM(quantity) as quantity FROM orders GROUP BY product_code`

The trick here is you want to use the `GROUP BY` method with the SUM method.

The `GROUP BY` method will automatically remove duplicate rows from the select.
The `SUM` will..well..SUM all the values that were grouped by the `GROUP BY` method.